# Check if text is visible with Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium, element, visible

I am making a script that will fill the forms to create a Gmail account with Python. When a username is already used a message becomes visible. In dutch: "Dez gebruikersnaam worst al gebruikt. Probeer been andere gebruikersnaam." To be able to deal with this I need to detect when this message is visible, but I have no idea how to do that. If anyone can help, that would be amazing

[image]

Comment: Check my answer. Is that working for you?

Comment: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@jsname='B34EJ']").text , and can applu validation accordingly.

Comment: inserted new XPath. can u try again?

Comment: If this worked for you can you accept it as the solution + upvote? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

path = '/home/avionerman/Documents/stack'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(path)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/intl/nl/gmail/about/#')

try:
    print('locating create account button')
    create_account_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('h-c-button')
except:
    print("error, couldn't find create account button")
try:
    create_account_button.click()
    print('navigating to creation page')
except:
    print('error navigating to creation page')
time.sleep(8)


handles = driver.window_handles
size = len(handles)

driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
print(driver.title)



first_name_input = driver.find_element_by_id('firstName')
first_name_input.click()
first_name_input.send_keys("WhateverYouWant")

last_name_input = driver.find_element_by_id('lastName')
last_name_input.click()
last_name_input.send_keys("WhateverYouWant2")

username_input = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username_input.click()
username_input.send_keys('papadopoulos')

pswd_input = driver.find_element_by_name('Passwd')
pswd_input.click()
pswd_input.send_keys('whateveryouwant')

pswd_conf_input = driver.find_element_by_name('ConfirmPasswd')
pswd_conf_input.click()
pswd_conf_input.send_keys('whateveryouwant')

next_button = driver.find_element_by_id("accountDetailsNext")
next_button.click()


# In the variable x I save the text that is included inside the specific xpath
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='view_container']/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div").text
print(x)

# I assert in order to check if the variable x has the proper text value (the expected one)
assert x == 'Dez gebruikersnaam worst al gebruikt. Probeer been andere gebruikersnaam.'


time.sleep(10)
```

In this way, if the assert passes mean that you see the warning message and in any other case the username for the mail is unique. So, the part of the code that I wrote to you, you can insert it inside if statements and you can handle it as you wish. If you need any further info feel free to ping me.

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason - Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div"}

keep getting this, with whatever path or element selector I use

Comment: That's really weird cause it's running on my machine. Hmm, can you search the XPath that I have in the code (manually)? I want you to tell me it exists in the code of the platform. Okay?

Comment: Can you also try to time.sleep(1) for one second before you try to locate the element, please?

Comment: Nevermind, it worked, I just made a small mistake, thank you for help once again!

Comment: If this worked for you can you accept it as the solution? :)